# Alternatives to ANOVA for kill assay

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, p-value, bioinformatics, dose-response

I'm trying to find an appropriate test to compare my data. I ran a 2-way repeated measures ANOVA to compare different drug concentrations' effects on bacterial population count at different time points. I believe the lack of internal variance in my data is causing massive differences in means to be statistically non-significant (although I am not certain this is my issue). At one given time point I have 0 bacteria in one treatment group and roughly 1*10^11 bacteria in the untreated group and this difference is not considered statistically significant (according to my ANOVA results). Are there any alternative statistical tests which I could use to compare the difference in bacteria present caused by each treatment type at an individual time point or alternatively compare the trend over time as a whole?
attached is some example data

| Time | Control | Conc_1 | Conc_ 10 | Conc_25 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4290450.16 | 1517752.6 | 846170.413 | 4689716.09 |
| 0 | 2226743.8 | 3248469.12 | 2876325.19 | 1424634.49 |
| 0 | 486908.236 | 1038625.72 | 1341289.48 | 4767606.93 |
| 1 | 26992173.3 | 886487.678 | 262.002109 | 0 |
| 1 | 24861517.6 | 4107951.05 | 139.779715 | 0 |
| 1 | 19821326.3 | 3121174.39 | 173.168544 | 0 |
| 2 | 179603392 | 183465.706 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 265731341 | 452418.349 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 8839336.17 | 1194998.62 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 4056524081 | 45170.0854 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3856768856 | 54914.1191 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1187620629 | 45715.1946 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1304819040 | 7443.03411 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2428866910 | 2773.56934 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 405955970 | 12211.78 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

1. Decide what your scientific goal is. Comparing cell densities at each time point does not seem useful to me; I would say that the *rate of change* (growth/mortality rate) is more informative in most cases. Sometimes density at a specified time point is considered interesting. But this is your decision to make.
2. If you decide on rate of change, then calculate these rates for each drug concentration. Exponential decline is a common assumption in cases such as yours, but you will need to consider whether this is appropriate. Calculating mortality rates will be somewhat difficult if your densities go to zero before time point 1 (as for Conc_25), but it will at least provide an approximate lower bound on the rate.
3. Analyse the treatment levels as *continuous* and not categorical i.e. use a regression rather than an ANOVA framework (in which you would compare individual levels). This is very common in ecotoxicology and microbiology, in which it is often called a dose-response curve. This allows you to meaningfully *interpolate* i.e. predict what the rate would be in between your measurement levels.
4. Dose-response curves often are logistic in shape and your data suggest that this may be appropriate in case as well. So fit a logistic regression to the data. You can use this to do the interpolation and also calculate parameters of general interest like LD50.